Firebase not connecting with Flutter project
I'm working with:

firebase_core: ^2.27.0
firebase_auth: ^4.17.8
cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8

I'm trying to Sign In with Email and Password with Firebase:
Future<User?> signInWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
 try {
   UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
     email: email,
     password: password,
   );
   return userCredential.user;
 } catch (e) {
   print('Error signing in: $e');
   throw Error();
 }
}

I have the GoogleService-Info.plist added inside ios > RunnerThe problem is that I'm getting this Error:

Error signing in: [firebase_auth/internal-error] Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c7ea30 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c4efa0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 220, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={     code = 400;     errors =     (                 {             domain = global;             message = "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND";             reason = invalid;         }     );     message = "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND"; }}}}`
Any ideas what can be wrong?

I'm trying to get to sign in with the Firebase Auth.

Your code is not well formatted and is very difficult to read.  I suggest reviewing some tips on how to format your text and code, then edit this question to be more readable.
